# How can TypeTag be serialized using kryo and chill?

Tags: scala, serialization, kryo

I use [chill-scala](https://github.com/twitter/chill) for serialization. I want to serialize a generic class that stores type parameter information so I pass `TypeTag[T]` as an implicit parameter:

```
import com.twitter.chill.{Output, ScalaKryoInstantiator}
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe.TypeTag

object TagTest extends App {
  class A[T](implicit val t: TypeTag[T]) {}
  val kryo = (new ScalaKryoInstantiator).setRegistrationRequired(false).newKryo()
  kryo.writeObject(new Output(new Array[Byte](100000)), new A[Int])
}
```

But for some reason serialization fails with `java.util.ConcurrentModificationException`:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.esotericsoftware.kryo.KryoException: java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
Serialization trace:
classes (sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader)
classLoader (scala.reflect.runtime.JavaMirrors$JavaMirror)
$outer (scala.reflect.runtime.JavaMirrors$JavaMirror$$anon$1)
currentOwner (scala.reflect.internal.Trees$TreeTypeSubstituter)
EmptyTreeTypeSubstituter (scala.reflect.runtime.JavaUniverse)
$outer (scala.reflect.api.TypeTags$PredefTypeTag)
t (TagTest$A)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.ObjectField.write(ObjectField.java:101)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.FieldSerializer.write(FieldSerializer.java:518)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.writeObject(Kryo.java:552)
```

Serialization fails with the same error if I try to serialize `typeOf[Int]` object and this suggests that `TypeTag` cannot be serialized.

What is the reason? How can I serialize `TypeTag`s?

Comment: According to the list that chill has on their Github page, they don't provide a serializer for `TypeTag` out-of-the-box. You may need to implement one yourself. https://github.com/twitter/chill#serializers-for-scala-classes